# AngleSharp return span id

Tags: c#, html, anglesharp

I'm trying to get a grip on AngleSharp by returning a specific part of an html.

So far that's my Code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
        {
            string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.planetradio.de/music/trackfinder.html");

            var parser = new HtmlParser();
            var document = parser.Parse(htmlCode);

            var blueListItemsLinq = document.All.Where(m => m.LocalName == "span id" && m.ClassList.Contains("headerTracklistCurrentSongArtist"));

            foreach (var item in blueListItemsLinq)


                label.Content = item;
        }
```

What i want it to return is the current Artist which should be in the html under:

```
<div id="headerTracklistCurrentSong">

        <span id="headerTracklistCurrentSongArtist"><a href="music/trackfinder.html">Olly Murs</a></span>
        <span id="headerTracklistCurrentSongTitle"><a href="music/trackfinder.html">Kiss Me</a></span>
```

But i seem to have made a mistake....so i'd be glad if someone could help me here and explain it to me...

Thanks in advance to everyone answering. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span elements are parsed as [`AngleSharp.Dom.Html.HtmlSpanElement`](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/blob/master/AngleSharp/Dom/Html/HtmlSpanElement.cs)
so your query should be:

```
var blueListItemsLinq = document.All.Where(m => m.LocalName == "span" && m.Id == "headerTracklistCurrentSongArtist");
```

Then you can get the text/values like this:

```
foreach (var item in blueListItemsLinq)
{
    label.Content = item.TextContent;  // "Olly Murs"
    var child = item.FirstChild as AngleSharp.Dom.Html.IHtmlAnchorElement;
    var text = child.Text;             // "Olly Murs"
    var path = child.PathName;         // "/music/trackfinder.html"
}
```

**UPDATED**

Since the currnt Artist names are shown in the table at "planetradio.de/music/trackfinder.html", you can get the names like this:

```
var hitfinderTable = document.All.Where(m => m.Id == "hitfindertable").First() as AngleSharp.Dom.Html.IHtmlTableElement;

foreach (var row in hitfinderTable.Rows)
{
    var artistName = row.Cells[2].TextContent;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! But i still can't get any info/text out from it....i don't get any Errors either though.... :(

Comment: @scitch You can get the text from `item.TextContent` in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: thanks again i'm really sorry to bother you that much. I tried that as well but it didn't seem to work....since i'm really new at this i can't actually be sure that i got the right html so sorry if i have to ask you but i want to make sure: 

This is the Code i want to get from the web element (at least i think that's the one i Need....):
<span id="headerTracklistCurrentSongArtist"><a href="music/trackfinder.html">Dj Snake &amp; Alunageorge</a></span>

And i'm getting the planetradio.de/Music/trackfinder.html so in theory it should be the right one.....shouldn't it?

Comment: @scitch So, do you want to get the text of "Dj Snake & Alunageorge" and "music/trackfinder.html" from the span element? I've updated my answer and hope it'll be helpful for you.

Comment: thanks again. :) 
But i didn't explain myself properly i think, sorry for that. I meant i use the planetradio.de/Music/trackfinder.html to get to the current Artist....but i don't get any value/text back....which confuses me and i don't actually know if that is the right html i use...

Comment: @scitch I checked planetradio.de/Music/trackfinder.html and there is "trackfinder" table. You want to get the aritist names from that table, right?

Comment: yes i just wanted to get the current Artist Name....thank you very much for checking i'm really grateful for that since i'm still really unsure about html. (°_°)

Comment: @scitch OK, I got it and updated my answer. You have to get the table element with the Id of "hitfindertable". Then you can get the table contents from the table element.

Comment: thank you very much! I don't think i would've gotten to this myself. At least i am now able to get something out of the html. :)) Though it's not the current song but the last one in the trackfinder-list....do you maybe have any idea on how i can get the only first one in the list?

Comment: If You mean the first row, `hitfinderTable.Rows.First()` should be the first one.

Comment: that's strange....it only gives me the last one regardless of i try to use hitfinderTable.Rows.Last() or first.

Comment: @scitch OK I'll check it. By the way, you might want to post this as another question because it is deviating from the first question.

Comment: thanks for your concern but i already found out that the way the above code works it just overrides each row and gives out the last one. 
So i just threw out the "foreach" and searched the first row for the current name that worked. Thanks for all your help. :)